# Is it possible to replace the enhanced ecommerce category in the dataLayer using GTM?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

The Enhanced Ecommerce dataLayer sends only the last subcategory to Google Analytics. I've shown which it sends in the first screenshot below

[image]

However, I would like the dataLayer to send the full category to Analytics (main category/subcategory etc.). I figured I could somehow use these breadcrumbs 2nd screenshot below.

[image]

Those all are list elements in a navigation menu. The list elements don't have an ID or a class, however, the whole menu (navigation) has a class. Is there any way to overwrite the category sent to Analytics with these breadcrumbs?

Here is an example of a dataLayer used:

```
ecommerce: {
currencyCode: "EUR",
detail: {
  products: [
    {
      name: "Men's waterproof mountain hiking shoes - SALOMON X U" +
            "LTRA 3 GTX",
      id: "8396527",
      reference: "2350488",
      price: "115",
      category: "Mountain Hiking Shoes",
      variant: "272@40, 8396527",
      link: "men-s-waterproof-mountain-hiking-shoes-salomon-x-ult" +
            "ra-3-gtx",
      model_id: "8396527",
      price_tax_exc: "95.04",
      wholesale_price: "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

},

Comment: You can grab your menu with a DOM element type variable that uses the menu's class (it will return the inner text). "/" is a valid delimiter for the content hierarchy in enhanced e-commerce ("The category to which the product belongs (e.g. Apparel). Use / as a delimiter to specify up to 5-levels of hierarchy " from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce). While I disagree that your question needs "more focus" it does not have enough information on the structure of your datalayer to be answerable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I edited the post and added an example of the dataLayer that is being used here. 
Also I've grabbed the menu and the variable works! :^), however there is a problem. The variable displays like this "All Sports Sports Nature Hiking Men Hiking Shoes Mountain Hiking Shoes" and there isn't a separator in there to separate the categories. Is there a way to send the info further with separators? Or even edit the data grabbed? So it would look like All Sports / Sports  / Nature / Hiking / Men /  Hiking Shoes / Mountain ?

Comment: Voted to reopen because surely there has been a misunderstanding on the side of the close voters - this is about one single very specific thing (overwriting the property of a dataLayer element in GTM) and does not lack focus at all.